# Homophone Riddle 6

Tags: riddle, word

This can't be too hard...

```
I am something you can climb or someone that you can see
I can be any hill or mountain
People kneeled for the brutality of the person you can see
```

One of these terms you might have not heard before but the other is common knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you a

> cop/kop

one definition is

> a heap or pile, which you can climb and perhaps a big one might be a hill or bigger

the second definition is

> policeman, which some NFL players take a knee to protest police brutality

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Peak/peek?

I am something you can climb or someone that you can see

> Youc an climb a peak, or look/peek to see a person.

I can be any hill or mountain

> Peak.

People kneeled for the brutality of the person you can see

> ???

Comment: Sorry, no, but here's a hint: Rot13  (Gurl ner obgu guerr-yrggre jbeqf)

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> Tor

I can be any hill or mountain

> Tor means a hill or mountain

People kneeled for the brutality of the person you can see

> [King Tor](https://wow.gamepedia.com/King_Tor)?

Comment: This is a homophone riddle, not homonym. Good try though :) +1